# How can i layout a search box

Tags: website-design, web-app

I have a search box with drop downs and checkboxes. The design is as follows:

[image]

I want to show that Regulation line Item and Control Test check boxes are child check boxes of Review checkbox. Item Priority drop down, Unlinked checkbox, Breach/Incident, Review and Go button are for all the filters. My design looks like the Go button is for Review checkbox. I want design it so that the user should be able to understand the relation between check boxes.

**I have made some modification in the UI:** 
[image]

Anyone has any suggestions for this.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, the "Unlink" and "Breach/Incident" is also childs of "Item priority"?

How about this example?

[image: 1]]

It will visualize the hierarchy of the settings and still respect the two types.

Comment: No "Unlink" and "Breach/Incident" are not child of "Item priority".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a search input field in your UI, so this might be called as a filter only.

Any conditional UI can be revealed when it is actually required, removing some of the clutter:

[image]

If the user clicks Review, you could expand the UI to show the remaining elements:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Technically and good practice is to have a real search tool at the top of the page. Filter items would be great tool for large set of results and most ecommerce place it either on left or right column.

If above option is not possible, you can dynamically implement a cascading options when an item is selected.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, @jonT. The plain text line to represent an interface is a bit unclear. If you select the "edit" option for your post, you can create and embed a Balsamiq mockup using the icon to the right of the image icon.

Comment: I don't have any means on drafting mockup on my current device. Anyhow, that is the beauty of having sketchy idea and low fidelity and would lead to some right solutions.

Answer (score -2):

@Mohini
Since the result depend for both the searches. Search button should be placed below the search area.